# MVC 4 : FormCollection Doesn't return radio button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm dynamically creating controls in Razor-View. Here I add some controls to my DOM depending on what data is in my object. But when I try to add a radiobutton I don't get it unless the value is constant. If I dynamically add two radio buttons with different values, FormCollection doesn't include those controls.

Please help me with this, as I fail to understand this behaviour. Ideally it should have just returned two radio buttons in collection.

```
foreach (var property in propertiesInner)
{
    if (property.Name == "OptionQuestion")
    {
        if (@item.ObjQuestions.QuestionType == 4)
        {
            <td>
                <table>                
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButton("RadTF", UniqueValue
                            , false, new { id = "RadTF",  @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @property.GetValue(itemInner, null)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        }
        else if (@item.ObjQuestions.QuestionType == 1) 
        { 
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBox("Chk"+@item.QuestionCode.ToString()+UniqueValue
                            , false, new { id = "Chk"+@item.QuestionCode.ToString()+UniqueValue
                                , @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
                            @property.GetValue(itemInner, null)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT 1:
**UniqueValue** is my forloop variable. So as to give each button a unique value.Also I tried concatenating this unique variable to my id like this:

```
@Html.RadioButton("RadTF"+UniqueValue, UniqueValue
, false, new { id = "RadTF"+UniqueValue
,  @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
```

***Value is constant*** means, if I generate radio buttons with same value I see them(or rather one of them) in the collection on post.

Comment: What do you mean "value is constant"? I can tell you that you are duplicating your IDs for radio button, which you don't want to do. What is `UniqueProperty`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your radio button group, you must ensure that each radio button:

- has a unique `id`
- has the same `name`

The `name` attribute is what groups different radio buttons together. You are using this overload:

```
public IHtmlString RadioButton(
    string name,
    Object value,
    bool isChecked,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Can you try this to create your radio buttons:

```
@Html.RadioButton("RadTF", UniqueProperty, false, new { id = "RadTF"+UniqueValue,  style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
```

If you still have issues, please post the markup of the rendered form.